# Hibernate WrongClassException for Custom Discriminators

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a concrete JPA entity superclass mapped with the `InheritanceType.JOINED` using discriminator columns, and have a couple subclasses entities that extend this superclass with additional properties.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
public class BaseEntity {
    // . . .
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SUBTYPE")
public class SubclassEntity extends BaseEntity {
    // . . .
}
```

There are cases where I want to specify additional discriminator values without having to explicitly define a subclass for every type (that is, not every "BaseEntity" specifies additional properties that warrant a subclass / separate table). This strategy works fine in the database design as well as the Java class hierarchy, however, Hibernate JPA does not allow this and throws a `WrongClassException` because there isn't a subclass mapped to the discriminator:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=entity-1] was not of the specified subclass [com.so.jpa.BaseEntity] : Discriminator: custom-1
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.getConcreteEntityTypeName(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3954)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:488)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1071)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:990)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1132)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:992)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:567)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:436)
    ...
```

In this case, I want Hibernate to return the concrete base entity `BaseEntity` rather than trying to instantiate a subclass. I don't see anything in the JPA spec (JSR 338) that indicates this shouldn't be possible (although the spec doesn't explicitly call out this scenario either).

Is there any way to allow JPA/Hibernate to allow custom discriminator types without requiring subclasses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Hibernate expects exactly one discriminator value per entity type. And I guess that there is no difference to other JPA providers, as you can't define more than one `DiscriminatorValue` for an entity class.

Even if you define no `DiscriminatorValue`, there will be exactly one:

> If the `DiscriminatorValue` annotation is not
>   specified and a discriminator column is used, a
>   provider-specific function will be used to generate a value
>   representing the entity type.  If the `DiscriminatorType` is
>   `STRING`, the discriminator value default is the
>   entity name.

(excerpt from the [JavaDoc of DiscriminatorValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorValue.html))

But you can define a `DiscriminatorFormula` instead of a `DiscriminatorColumn` in Hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorFormula(
    "CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('SUBTYPE', 'SUBTYPE-2', ...) THEN TYPE ELSE 'BaseEntity'")
public class BaseEntity {
    // . . .
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SUBTYPE")
public class SubclassEntity extends BaseEntity {
    // ...
}
```

Disadvantage of that solution: You need to declare the discriminator values of all subtypes in `BaseEntity`.

Comment: Thanks. This wasn't the answer I was hoping for :-), but was still helpful in confirming that there really isn't a valid way to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is even a simpler solution to this problem. You could use a `@DiscriminatorValue("not null")`, like this:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("not null")
public class MiscSubclassEntity extends BaseEntity {
    // . . .
}
```

This way, whenever a non-mapped discriminator value is found, a `MiscSubclassEntity` will be used instead. For more on this topic, check this [Hibernate blog post](http://in.relation.to/2016/07/19/null-andnot-null-discriminator-values/).